# Flooring floating-point modulo

Tags: c

I want to create a modulo-like function which can work with `double`-precision floats rather than `int`s. Another important factor is that the function must round towards negative infinity, rather than zero.

I have a couple of methods which work, but I believe them to be slow for a function which will be called many times in loops:

```
// A suggested method
double reduce_range(double x, const double max) {
    x /= max; // Normalize to [0,1)
    x -= (int) x;
    x += 1.0;
    x -= (int) x;
    return x * max; // Denormalize
}

// My own simple implementation
double reduce_range(const double x, const double max) {
    return x - floor(x / max) * max;
}
```

Both seem to work, but the second uses `floor` (which seems to be a bit of a bottleneck for these sorts of things) and the first repeatedly casts to int and subtracts. Is there not some faster way to do this (or to allow the compiler to take care of it)?

Alternatively, how about this:

```
double reduce_range(double x, const double max) {
    x = fmod(x, max);
    if(x < 0) x += max;
    return x;
}
```

Is it going to be greatly slowed down by the branching `if`?

---

Edit: some example inputs and outputs:

```
(5.0, 7.0) >> 5.0
(8.5, 7.0) >> 1.5
(-2.3, 7.0) >> 4.7
```

Comment: But is it actually a branching `if`? At least with SSE2, I could see that compiling to masking (clang 3.7 actually does this). Depends on your target and compiler.

Comment: @harold x86, Windows, gcc with MinGW.

Comment: May want to review `double fmod(double x, double y);` from `math.h`.

Comment: Unclear of the need for rounding as FP modulo can be exact.  Suggest posting some sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: The methods in your post lose precision.  How imprecise do you want?  Suggest you compare your results to the standard function `fmod(x,y)` which computes the floating-point remainder of `x/y`.

Comment: `fmod` is used in the third method. I am fine with losing a little bit of precision, as long as the result is within the range and roughly where it should be. Obviously extra precision does no harm.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the branch, then possibly this might be better, if it's cheaper to load an integer into the fpu:

```
x += max * (x < 0);
```